# detect window resize due to download bar (chrome, latest edge, firefox) vs general window resize

Tags: javascript, resize, window, window-resize

I have a legacy webapp which has super complicated resize event bound. It supports desktop-like windows within the page (I know...) and they all scale on resize.

This actually performs fine except in one case: when you click on a PDF link on this app and it downloads to the browser, then opens the PDF in a new tab instead of system viewer (if that is the user's browser setting). Then when closing the tab and going back to the app's tab, it spends an inordinate amount of time on resize logic (normal resize logic timing from click dragging window corner is ~1-3s, this is like ~15-20s)

I think multiple resizes may be triggered simultaneously when the downloads bar pops into the page and the new tab opens. There is already a very large (1500ms) debouncer in place but maybe something about opening a new tab / the download bar resizing instead of click-drag resizing makes the debouncer not apply in this case) and causes this huge slowdown when closing the PDF and going back to the app tab.

we cannot just tell users to have their PDFs open in system viewer, and I need some guidance on how to even start trying to fix this issue. (or help on the path I'm trying).

The path I'm trying is: i want to detect a resize that is from the downloads bar as opposed to for other reasons (maybe the y delta being exactly the same as downloads bar height?? is there a way to do that?) and just return false, we dont care much if that 50-100px is not adjusted for and when they close it, it will resize normally anyway.

Comment: I've found workaround on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62911452/can-we-distinguish-the-reason-that-cause-a-window-resize-event-in-chrome). Check the accepted answear

Comment: Is your site/page publicly available?

Comment: First, are your PDF files hosted on the same hostname? if so you can use the HTML5 `download` attribute on your links. this would prevent all of the issues you are currently having.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I've used to deal with being flooded with events in the past

```
import raf from 'raf'

let rafId = null

function onResize() {
  if(!rafId) {
    rafId = raf(() => {
      your_resize_function()
      rafId = null
    })
  }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', onResize)
```

Its using `requestAnimationFrame` to delay the kickoff and a simple flag to stop it being called more than once. I find this much better than using `debounce()` as it adapts to how busy the call stack is.

Comment: OP said it was legacy, I'd assume that means no `npm`/`import`, maybe show an alternative with `window.requestAnimationFrame` as well?

Comment: `raf` has support for `IE` 6 and `Safari 4`. Imho is extreme legacy. Also OP can always copy code from github to the project, so `npm` shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @ulou "legacy" in this context has nothing to do with browser support and everything to do with code architecture. my previous comment was referring to the possibility that their existing system has no concept of modules/`import`/`export` etc. Using `requestAnimationFrame` is a good idea in this situation, but the example given may be overcomplicated for OP or future readers.

Comment: Happy to update if OP asks, basically swap the first line to `const raf = window.requestAnimationFrame` as I guess we don't need to care about IE 6 these days

Comment: Actually what happened to the OP? It’s a bit odd to put such a large bounty up and then disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by adding a "busy" flag in your procedure, set to True at the start, and False when exiting. This way, at least you can catch recurring events (if true return).

In some quick tests, a simple canvas in a div with auto-resize scales when the browser (tested Chrome and Firefox, Explorer always an outlier) shows the bar. Initial scale - new scale) * original width = pixels different.

Answer (score 0):

How are you detecting the size of the window when the events occur?

I had a similar issue, and discovered a better way to detect the window's size:

```
let windowHeight = window.document.documentElement.clientHeight;
let windowWidth = window.document.documentElement.clientWidth;
```

Detecting the size in this exact manner took things into consideration that other ways didn't. It may solve your issue with that download bar.